# Getting a nullpointerexception on setting custom adapter if started on landscape mode

Tags: android, gridview

I encountered some weird problem on my project wherein it triggers null pointer adapter when started on landscape mode. Now the thing is I have a gridview just to hold a buttons due to some issues wherein this is the only best choice I have. Now the adapter is just plain simple:

```
public class ActionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;

    public ActionsAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View  rowView;
        if(i==0) {
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button1, viewGroup, false);
            Button button1 = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showPage();
                }
            });
        }else{
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button2, viewGroup, false);

        }


        return rowView;


    }

private void showPage(){
        //TODO show page
    }
```

Now what I did is just to simply set this adapter into my gridview the natural way I think:

```
actions.setAdapter(new ActionsAdapter(getActivity()));
```

Now this works perfectly on portrait mode but if started on landscapemode it returns a nullpointer exeption which points me on the code above in setting the adapter.

Here is the full logs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gmanmi.news.papalvisit2014.mobile, PID: 18353
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.kahel.sample.fragments.Testfragment.onCreateView(Testfragment.java:93)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the onCreateView:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grid_actions, container, false);

        actions = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_actions);
        actions.setAdapter(new ActionsAdapter(getActivity()));
 actions.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
enter code here
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position==1){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Show action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: can you post Testfragment's onCreateView ?

Comment: Posted the onCreateView though I need to truncate some parts (Setting the Views) on which I'm sure is not the reason for the error.

Comment: Possibly view.findViewById(R.id.grid_actions) is returning null. If you have a separate xml for landscape then check that the grid_actions id is identical in both portrait and landscape layouts.

Comment: I only have one xml layout. I also think that the view returns null but don't know why it only happens when started on landscape.

Comment: Okay, after checking it I already pointed out the real cause of the problem is that because previously I have a separate xml layout for landscape which I already deleted but haven't cleaned it yet making a null pointer. On first clean I'm not sure why it doesn't work but on second try it do the job. Thanks @samgak for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with calling `getActivity` in `onCreateView`. You cannot do that safely because there is no guarantee the Activity is already fully created at that point, hence the NPE. Move the call to `setAdapter` and subsequent ones to `onActivityCreated`.

Maybe [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) could help you understand better how to handle this.

Comment: Tried it already but still points me on the setting of adapter as error.

Comment: Already solved it. It's just that the clean project didn't do it's job on my first try after deleting the other xml layout. Anyways, I really appreciate this solution and implement it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@2Dee is right when you use `getActivity` in `onCreateView`, you cannot know if this activity is created at this point.

Look at his answer for more precision !!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you find out that the Activity is fully created in onViewCreated ? I can't seem to find documentation on when one can count on having the Activity correctly created...

Comment: @2Dee Mm Indeed, you are sure the view hierarchy of the fragment has been completely created as specified in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,android.os.Bundle) but not the parent containing the fragment.

Comment: Moreover, I remember reading that onActivityCreated was called as a consequence of the Activity's onCreate method returning, whereas onViewCreated is called as a result of the Fragment's OnCreateView method returning. You have the added benefit of the fact that savedInstanceState could be used to retain the content of the adapter between orientation changes to avoid unnecessary network activity, so unless one has an adamant reason to move the calls elsewhere, I'd recommend going the safest route and using onActivityCreated. Interesting discussion :)

Comment: I believe so, mainly because it will be clearer to future readers.